# s6: service not logging anything

Tags: linux, logging

I'm trying to get `s6-log` to work on a service file I've written. The service file looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/execlineb -P

/usr/local/bin/s6-setuidgid [username]

/usr/bin/[actual_service]
```

and I also created `[servicedir]/log/run`, which is just

```
#!/usr/local/bin/execlineb -P

/usr/local/bin/s6-log T /var/log/[servicename]
```

After starting it, s6-logger is running, `/var/log/[servicename]/current` is nicely created, and yet, it's empty. I even checked whether the service is writing things out with `strace -p [supervisor pid] -f` to catch even startup messages... and it works, writing things to file descriptor 2, which is stderr.

Why isn't this written to the log file?

Answer (score 1):

Note the **... to file descriptor 2, which is stderr** part.

`s6-supervise` will only pick up logs written to stdout. It will ignore stderr, unless it's explicitly redirected to stdout explicitly, for example by adding

`fdmove -c 2 1`

to the service run script.